# Retrieve data from Db set by combobox and display to textbox

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox

This is my code

```
s2="SELECT Notes From A WHERE ATotalNo =" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem +"" 
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand=New OleDbCommand(s2,myConnection1) 
cmd.CommandText=s2 TextBox1.Text=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString()
```

And I am getting following error:-

> Erorr: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: s2="SELECT Notes From A WHERE ATotalNo ="+ ComboBox1.SelectedItem

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Apply `ToString()` on SelectedItem and why to convert result set to integer, if you only want to show it in textbox?

Try this,

```
s2 = "SELECT Notes From A WHERE ATotalNo = "& ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() &"" 

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(s2, myConnection1) 
cmd.CommandText = s2 
TextBox1.Text = "" & cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Here the resultset is concatenated with a empty string to make it as whole string.

If column `ATotalNo` is of type VARCHAR then decorate selectedItem value with single quotes. Like,

```
s2 = "SELECT Notes From A WHERE ATotalNo = '"& ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() &"'"
```

Hope it helps thanks.

Comment: same error 
Erorr: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: last update gives same error Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Does your comboBox have Text and Value different? and what type of your ATotalNo column is?. Try this once, `s2 = "SELECT Notes From A WHERE ATotalNo =" + ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString() +""`.

Comment: combobox the value 1 or 2 to10 AtotalNo 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: I found the problem which was in '  ' bteween combobox this is the code ` s2 = "SELECT Notes From A WHERE ATotalNo = ' " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem +  " ' "`
       `

Comment: Thanks you @ BabyDuck

Comment: That means your `AtotalNo` is of type varchar. I update the answer for other readers.